# form type="url" POST to PHP

Tags: php, html, post, forms, http-post

So I have a form that requires a user to submit their website to a form. Here is the html line:

```
<input type='url' name='link'>
```

And I'm using `<input type="submit" value="submit" formmethod="post">` to submit the form to a php

And I'm trying to retrieve the values in my php file with:

```
$link = $_POST['link'];
```

Why isn't this working?  At first I thought it was because I had `htmlspecialchars()` but it's not coming through without it either.  I can't find anything in any google search that even mentions anything related to this kind of problem (with a `type="url"` form)

What do I need to do to process form data with type of "url" in PHP with a $_POST?

Comment: method=post, not formmethod

Comment: Do you have more than one input in the form? if yes, they work?

Comment: [formmethod](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/#formmethod) exists in html5, and it's supposed to be an attribute on submit & image input types. Can you post the full form html that you've used?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear.  I had `<input type="submit" value="submit" formmethod="post">`   BUT I just also tried to instead to put `method="post"` in the <form> tag with no luck.  All of my other input types are sending as they should, but not `type="url"`   I tried a test page with only one form tag in it and that did send the url as expected.  I compared it with my code in the full page and see no differences.  I will keep adding to my test page until it matches the real page and see what makes it break.

Comment: try change the type="url" to type="text" and check the result.

Comment: Ugh... just went back to my full php page.  Commented everything out and did `echo $_POST['link']`.... it worked fine.  I uncommented everything and tried again... works great.  I have no idea what could be different now, but it works.  Happy that it works.... but super frustrated it took all evening.  Must have been a silly typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong,

```
method="post"
```

Its only method, not formmethod

Also make sure, you dont have one more for element name with `link`.

Comment: [formmethod](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-introduction-and-new-attributes/#formmethod)

Answer (score 0):

Get your form method to be set to post e.g

```
<form method=post>,
```

if you submit the form and in the url in your browser u can see some more inf then be sure 2 check your form method